# Android Bluetooth issue when reading from inputsream in HTC Desire Z

Tags: android, bluetooth, htc-android

I am doing a project dealing with transmitting image files from BTM-182 Bluetooth module to Android phone. The program is based on Android 2.0.

I have read the Bluetooth Chat program from google, and I can establish the connection using standard Bluetooth SPP profile UUID. I can obtain the inputstream and outputstream from BluetoothSocket in the program.

The problem happens in my HTC Desire Z (Android 2.2, not rooted) when reading from inputstream. I need to read 38400 byte of data each time, but the program seems that it can only read about 24000 byte and hangs, no more bytes can be read and no exceptions are thrown!

However, the same program runs fine on another phone with unmodified Android 2.2 system which is rooted.

I have already googled that it seems that the Bluetooth SPP profile in HTC Desire is broken and has a buggy implementation:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8382 
I don't know whether my Desire Z suffers the same buggy implementation.

Any suggestions of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out the Amarino API. [www.amarino-toolkit.net/](http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/)